# kindで表示される記法に納得がいかない

Tags: haskell

下記のように型引数の個数を変えて kind を確認してみました。
型引数を受け取らないのに `*` がついているのがよくわかりません。

また、型引数が複数以上の最後の `-> *` の部分は具体的にどんな型が返ることを言っているのでしょうか？ 下記 `BBB` の場合は `-> *` が示してるのは `BBB型` のことですか？

**型引数をなにも受けとらない場合**

```
Prelude> data AAA = AAA
Prelude> :kind AAA
AAA :: *
```

**型引数をひとつ受け取る場合**

```
Prelude> data BBB a = BBB
Prelude> :kind BBB
BBB :: * -> *
```

**型引数を2つ受け取る場合**

```
Prelude> data CCC a b = CCC
Prelude> :kind CCC
CCC :: * -> * -> *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` という kind は、何も型引数を受け取らない「単なる型」を表すものです。

たとえば `Int` という型は、`1` とか `-2` とか `3 + 5` とかいった、値が求まれば整数になる項たちを表しているものです。同じように `*` という kind は、`Int` とか `String` とか `Maybe Int` とかいった単なる型たちを表しているものなのです。

`Maybe` には `* -> *` という kind が付きますが、これは型を受け取って型を返すことを表しています。`Maybe :: * -> *` と `Int :: *` があって、これを型適用すると `Maybe Int :: *` になる訳です。

kind で考えるのが分かりづらければ、まず型で考えてみてください。`Int` は整数を表す型で、`Int -> Int` は整数を受け取って整数を返す関数です。たとえば絶対値を返す関数 `abs :: Int -> Int` と整数 `-2 :: Int` があって、これを適用すると `abs (-2) :: Int` になる訳です。これと類似のお話を型のレベルへ 1 段上げたものが kind です。

Comment: つまり `*` 単体と `* ->` で`*`の意味が何も受け取らないから何か受け取るに意味が変わるんですね？

Comment: 違います、`*` の意味は変わっていません。説明を書き加えてみました。

Comment: `::*` は `型引数を受け取らない単なる型`、`-> *` と矢印の最後の型も `型引数を受け取らない単なる型` つまり、矢印の一番最後の `*` は、`もうこれ以上型引数を受け取らない型` と言い換えれそうですね？

Comment: つまり `Maybe :: * -> *` は Maybeは型引数を1つ受け取って、これ以上何も型引数を受け取らない型を返す。

Comment: そして `Int :: *` は Intは型引数を受け取らない型 と読める。こういうことですね？

Comment: そして 型引数を受け取らない型とは言い換えると「単なる型」であるということなので`*`はどこに書いても結局「単なる型」を意味するということですね（理解）